# ssh public key on multiple servers

Tags: ssh

Partially theoretical question about SSH.

I have multiple remote machines.

I want to login to these remote machines without a password. So I am doing `ssh-keygen` on a dev machine, and copy the public key to the first machine into `autorized_keys`. Connection successful.

Now, what to do with a second, third, etc remote machines? Should I reuse the very same public key and copy it into the `authorized_keys` on other machines? Or should I generate a new key for each remote? Could the same public key on different machines be a security risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can share them

In general SSH **public** keys can be shared between hosts safely.  One of the big advantages to public/private key cryptography is the fact that you don't need a new key for every server/client pair.

Put plainly, giving a server your public key **does not** give it access to impersonate you.  It's "impossible" (trillions of years of CPU time) to get from public to private key.

### One Exception

There's a weakness to using "key agents" [described here](https://smallstep.com/blog/ssh-agent-explained/#agent-forwarding-comes-with-a-risk).  The server's system administrator (or `root`) can use your local client's key agent while you are connected.

Practically this means that while you are connected and using an SSH key agent, the system administrator could impersonate you on another server.

Across organisational boundaries you should avoid using an agent or perhaps find another key agent that prompts you when it's being used.  Otherwise you should not share public/private keys between organisations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you keep your private key secure (not shared with anyone, protected with password) I do not see any serious reason against usage of the same public key on many machines.